# Attaching DB with full-text catalogs under a different name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a database with regular full-text catalogs. I want to detach this database, copy it to a different server and attach it under a different name (same name but with '_BAK' appended to it).  I am using SQL Server 2005.

Here is the error trying to attach DATABASE with full-text catalogs under the name DATABASE_BAK

```
Warning: Identity or last population complete time of full-text catalog in 
directory 'E:\DATABASE\Name_FullText' does not match database 'DATABASE'. 
The full-text catalog cannot be attached.
```

- Is there a way to attach a database w/ full-text under a different name?
- If not what other options do I have?

  - Attach without fulltext?
  - Drop the full-text at detach and recreate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just attach the database and then rename it once attached?